# Sard's Lemma in one dimmension

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> **Sard's lemma in one dimmension:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^1$. Let $$C=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : f'(x)=0\}$$ be the set of critical points of $f$. Then $f(C)$ has measure $0$.

I believe I have found a proof but I'm not sure if its correct. I would appreciate if someone could point out any flaws.

The basic idea is this:

If $a$ is a critical point of $f$, then if $x$ is close to $a$, $f'(x)$ is close to $f'(a)=0$, so $f(x)$ varies by a small amount if $x$ stays close to $a$. Our goal is to cover $\mathbb{R}$ by countably many intervals $I_k$ and make the $I_k$ small enough so that if $I_k$ contains a critical point $a$, then $f(I_k)$ will be an interval whose size is small. Then $f(C)$ will be contained in the union of countably many small intervals, which is a rough way of saying $f(C)$ has measure zero.

Now more rigorously:

---

**Step I:**

Since a $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of intervals of the type $[n,n+1]$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and a countable union of measure-zero sets is measure-zero, it suffices to show that $f(C) \cap [n,n+1]$ is measure-zero for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It suffices to take the case $n=0$.

**Step II:**

Let $S=\{x \in [0,1] : f'(x)=0\}$. Let $a \in S$. Let's **fix $\delta>0$**. Since $f'$ is continuous the closed, bounded interval $[0,1]$ it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ by Heine-Cantor, and thus there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $\forall x,y \in [0,1]$, $|x-y|<\epsilon_0 \implies |f'(x)-f'(y)|<\delta$.

Hence $\forall x \in [0,1]$, $|x-a|<\epsilon_0 \implies |f'(x)|<\delta$

By Cauchy's mean value theorem, if $\epsilon>0$ then for all $x\neq a$ such that $|x-a|<\epsilon$, there exists $c$ such that $|c-a|<\epsilon$ and

$[f(x)-f(a)]/[x-a]=f'(c)$.

Choosing $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$, we have $|f'(c)|<\delta$ and thus $|f(x)-f(a)|<\delta|x-a|<\delta\epsilon$.

In summary, for all $x \in [0,1]$, for all $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$, we have: $|x-a|<\epsilon \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\delta\epsilon$. (***)

**Step III:**

Now, lets choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/N<\epsilon_0$. Then since $[0,1]=\bigcup_{0 \le k<N}[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}]$,

$f(S)=\bigcup_{0 \le k<N}f(S \cap[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}])$

If $S\cap[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}]=\emptyset$, then its image is empty. Otherwise $[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}]$ contains a critical point $a$ and since $\forall x\in [\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}]$, $|x-a|\le 1/N$, applying (***) we get $\forall x \in [\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}]$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\delta/N$. Thus $f([\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}])$ is a closed interval of length at most $2\delta/N$. Finally, since

$f(S \cap[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}]) \subset f([\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}])$

we have $f(S)$ is contained in the union of at most $N$ closed intervals each of whose length is at most $2\delta/N$.Thus the sum of their lengths is at most $2\delta$.

In conclusion, for any $\delta>0$, we can cover $f(S)$ by finitely many closed intervals whose total length is at most $2\delta$. Thus $f(S)$ has measure zero, and we're done.

Comment: For a constant function the set of critical points is the entire $\mathbb{R}$. I don't see where the proof uses the fact that $f$ is _not_ constant.

Comment: @user58697 The theorem is about the image by f of the set of critical points, not this set itself.

Comment: @user58697: Indeed if $f$ is constant, the set of critical points $C$ is $\mathbb{R}$. What we are trying to prove is that $f(C)$ is always of measure zero. In this case, $f(C)$ is a singelton, thus certainly of measure zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof looks very good, I think you can shorten it a little by using

$$
\delta(t) = \sup \{|f^\prime(y)-f^\prime(x)|,\ x, y\in [0,1], |y-x|\le t\}
$$

Then $\delta(t)\to 0$ when $t \to 0^+$, and for any subinterval $I\subset [0,1]$, if $I$ contains a critical point $a$, then for $x \in I$
$$
|f(x)-f(a)| = |x-a| |f^\prime(c)| = |x-a| |f^\prime(c) - f^\prime(a)| \le \mu(I) \delta(\mu(I))
$$
hence if $I$ contains a critical point
$$
\mu(f(I))\le 2 \mu(I) \delta(\mu(I))
$$
Now covering $[0,1]$ in $N$ intervals of length $1/N$ yields
$$
\mu(f(C \cap [0,1]))\le 2 N \times \frac{1}{N} \delta\left(\frac{1}{N}\right) = 2
\delta\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\longrightarrow 0$$